# Could you verify correctness of a logical proposition?

Tags: logic

Here is a problem from one of the exercises in the book "Logic in Computer Science". The question asks to create a proposition for the following statement.

> If a request occurs, then either it will eventually be acknowledged, or the requesting process won't ever be able to make progress.

The proposition that I came up with is as the following.

$$p \implies (q \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor \neg r)$$

Here *p* symbolises *"request occurred"*, *q* symbolises *"request acknowledged"*, and *r* symbolises *"request making no progress"*.

But in the official solution manual, I see the following as a solution.

$$p \implies (q \lor r)$$

I think the solution is incorrect as it doesn't exclude the possibility of both the proposition *q* and *r* happening simultaneously. One can see in the above statement that the phrase "either... or ..." indicate exclusivity.

Does my reasoning have a flaw?

Comment: This is the problem with natural language and its inherent ambiguity.  I think you make a good case for the interpretation you had for your answer.  However, note that it is possible that the request is acknowledged, but nonetheless, due to some other reason, no progress can be made on the request.

Comment: Did you mean a pr**o**position?

Comment: @amWhy I agree with the fact that acknowledging and processing a request need not be a pair of exclusive events and natural language is inherently ambiguous. Do you think the statement is not sufficient enough to pin down the accurate proposition out of the above-mentioned ones?

Comment: I think the text's solution is correct.  That much is certainly translatable to logic.